# Sourcing & Filtering - The field type must match the type of the field you are sourcing from (Text Area)

Tags: field, customization, netsuite, record

I created a custom record and I am trying to create field (List/Record : Adress Book)  sourced from all address of Vendor Field.

Here the vendor field

[image]

Here the Address Book field

[image]

And here the different Test and result I got

First configuration test

[image]

Result : "The field type must match the type of the field you are sourcing from (Text Area)."

Second configuration test

[image]

Result : "The list or record type of the field or source (Vendor) must match the list or record type of the field you are filtering by (Entity)."

Answer (score 1):

It is saying that "Address" is technically a text area representation of the address, not actually a reference to the address book. If you make your "Delivery address" field of type text area and do configuration 1, then it will work

Comment: Yes , but I need to keep somehow the record Address, to be able to do some saved search on this field (ex: address.country / address.city, ...). So the solution to use text area doesn't fit

Comment: In which case I believe you will need a script. The address is actually a sub record and therefore cannot be accessed by workflow or sourcing. This is because what you see in the Vendor record is just a convenient display of the default billing. Technically a Vendor can have many addresses

Comment: Another option would be to create fields for each piece - Country etc, and source from Bill To Country etc.

Comment: I built something similar expecting a better solution